# How to display date from database in Django form without day

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I was looking for a solution but nowhere to find the right answer. Maybe the answer I am looking for does not exist, so I decided to ask a question here just in case.

I try to show a date without a day. But the problem is that the date is displayed as one of form fields that I create from the model in the database. I explained this because I am not trying to show only the date separately in the temple but the whole form. I'm showing the form in the template using {{form.as_p}}. My date always shows dd.mm.YYYY, but I want to display a date without a day. The form is used to update existing data in the database. Is there a solution, to define certain parameters in the form class I created in the forms.py file or I must do something else?

Comment: So `mm.YYYY` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
    message = forms.CharField(
        max_length=2000,
        widget=forms.Textarea(),
        help_text='Write here your message!'
    )
    source = forms.CharField(       # A hidden input for internal use
        max_length=50,              # tell from which page the user sent the message
        widget=forms.HiddenInput()
    )
```

You can render it manually like this:

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <ul>
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}

  {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
    {% if hidden_field.errors %}
      <ul>
        {% for error in hidden_field.errors %}
          <li>(Hidden field {{ hidden_field.name }}) {{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {{ hidden_field }}
  {% endfor %}

  <table border="1">
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
      <tr>
        <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
        <td>
          {% if field.errors %}
            <ul>
              {% for error in field.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
          {{ field }}
          {% if field.help_text %}
            <br />{{ field.help_text }}
          {% endif %}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now you can apply date filter to your fields:
{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}

You can read more about date filter as pre your need i.e., to get only date or time : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date